# AWS instance outof memory issue

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are running a one page simple wp website and there is other resources working with codeigniter. we are running codeigniter APIs and admin stuff without any issue for months but suddenly we have added installed wordpress in root and started one page website so it stops working.

Everyday we have to restart EC2 instace to start working again. we have checked `bandwidth` and it reaches `5000` plus which is very high.

Because genearally without wordpress its below `10` only now after wordpress installation it reaches `5000+` which is very high.

We are running `AWS Micro instance` with Elastic IP. any help will be appreciated

Comment: Looks like your wordpress is receiving a lot of traffic from the internet to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check couple of things before you find the solution

1. How much traffic is coming to your wordpress website. I am not an expert of wordpress but there should be some sort of logs for incoming request.
2. You need to find whether the memory in your micro instance is good enough for the traffic/request processing. If required, you may need to look into profiling your code to find any performance bottleneck.

There is a likelihood that your website maybe getting some non-legitimate traffic from an attacker/craweler. To protect from such attacks you need to look into using WAF/Shield AWS services